# Dropdown SubMenus Based on Roles Stopped Working

Tags: navigation

My site has a menu/top nav of course and I have various dropdown/sub menus.  Yesterday it was all working fine.  If you are an **anonymous** user, you see a particular menu item, that has a particular dropdown.  If an **authenticated** user, you see another menu.

Today, I looked at the page, first as an anonymous users, the top level menus are there, **but** when I hover the dropdown menus items do not appear.  I then logged in and same thing, the top level is there, but the hover does not display the submenus at all.

**I then logged in as the admin** and **can see** the top level menu and on hover, all the submenus appear.  So natural thought, something happened with the permissions settings, but I checked everything "**seems**" fine.  The only changes between today and yesterday afternoon where several updates to a stylesheet and I did add/install several modules *[webform, token, date, calendar geolocation]*, I have not done anything to turn off the menu.  The top level is checked to **show as expanded** and of course, they show and function correctly when I am logged in as the **ADMIN**.

*To explain my setup*: where needed, I created two top menus for "speakers" for example:
speakers ->one ->two (permissions set to display for anonymous users)
speakers ->five ->twelve  (permissions set to display for anonymous users)

In the above example, anonymous user goes to page, hovers over speakers menu item, and should see in the dropdown [submenu items one and two] and this has been working for weeks now.  Same would apply for the authenticated user hovering over the second "speakers" and seeing [five and twelve in the submenu].

How do I debug this scenario to find out what is wrong?  I've been doing this long enough to know it is probably something I have done, but after checking permissions, checking menu visibility - oh I am also using the "**Menu Per role"** module that has been in place for weeks, I would like some insight on how to attack this problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just posting my solution for those who may come after.

As I stated above, I did suspect that it was something I had or had not done to cause this issue.  Knowing for certain that the only changes made were related to stylesheet updates, which I knew could not cause this problem, and loading of new modules,  I decided I would have to uninstall them one-by-one, but before doing that, I went over the modules I installed yesterday **[just a note: the reason I didn't see this issue yesterday was because the correct display had been cached]** and thought about the problem and which module would most relate to that problem, so I started with jquery_update. [jquery/javascript typically used for these types of effects, hover onClick, etc.]

I installed jquery_update yesterday.  I did change the admin display option to version 1.7, but I left the working option at 1.10.  I disabled the module, refreshed my page and the submenus did appear on hover.

I was going to uninstall the module completely, then decided to set the working version back to 1.8 and the dropdown on hover continued to work.

I have not had time to really look, but the original developer set up the site with an older theme and I bet there is a conflict in the version used in the theme he/she chose and the most recent version of jquery.

Hopefully this will save someone a few hours of their life.

I do still love Drupal.